# Is it possible to replicate a Postgresql database from an Amazon RDS to another Amazon RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Postgresql database in my Amazon RDS and I want to replicate it into another Amazon RDS so I can bifurcate the connections depending on the situation but keeping the same data.

Besides, it would be very nice if I could replicate just some tables from the main database and be able to do INSERTS into the non-replicated tables from the second database. Like this:

```
**DB1**      **DB2**
DB1.table1   DB2.table1
DB1.table2   DB2.table2
DB1.table3   DB2.table3
DB1.table4   DB2.table_log
DB1.table5
```

Replicate `table1`, `table2` and `table3` from `DB1` to `DB2`, not replicate `table4` and `table5` and still be able to `INSERT` into `table_log`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) to replicate specific tables from one database to another, and you can even alter the schema when you replicate if you want. Be sure to create a [change data capture (CDC) replication task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Task.CDC.html) so changes in the source database get immediately pushed to your target database.